# Error- Adding Connection string during installation C# Project.exe

Tags: c#, connection, installation

I followed this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/446121/Adding-connection-string-during-installation but getting error in installation

Error 1001 Unable to create an instance of the ProjectName.Installer installer type --> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation -->Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

my Installer.cs code:

```
 public Installer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string dataSource = "Data Source =" + Context.Parameters["DataSource"];
            string initialcatalog = "Initial Catalog=" + Context.Parameters["InitialCatalog"];
            string userid = "User ID=" + Context.Parameters["UserID"];
            string password = "Password=" + Context.Parameters["Password"];
            dataSource = dataSource + ";" + initialcatalog;
            dataSource = dataSource + ";Persist Security Info=True;"+userid+";"+password;
            MessageBox.Show("instance=" + dataSource);
            ExeConfigurationFileMap map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
            MessageBox.Show(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + ".config");
            //Getting the path location 
            string configFile = string.Concat(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, ".config");
            map.ExeConfigFilename = configFile;
            System.Configuration.Configuration config = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
            OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, System.Configuration.ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            string connectionsection = config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings
            ["TECHNOSOFT.Properties.Settings.Tech2014ConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;

            ConnectionStringSettings connectionstring = null;
            if (connectionsection != null)
            {
                config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Remove("TECHNOSOFT.Properties.Settings.Tech2014ConnectionString1");
                MessageBox.Show("removing existing Connection String");
            }

            connectionstring = new ConnectionStringSettings("TECHNOSOFT.Properties.Settings.Tech2014ConnectionString1", dataSource);
            config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Add(connectionstring);

            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true);
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
        }
```

What iam missing? Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Context property would still be null inside the constructor. That is why you are getting a null exception.
Instead, move your logic to the Install() method.

```
public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
{
    // Access context and put your logic here
}
```